# Relacionamento many to many com select multiplo no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tenho os models Post e Tag com um relacionamento many to many. Ao cadastrar um post as tags previamente cadastradas aparecem normalmente no select e consigo salvar no banco. No form de editar não estou conseguindo fazer com que apareça as tags selecionadas e as disponíveis. Ou aparece as selecionadas ou aparece as disponíveis tirando um foreach e deixando o outro. Da forma como está, aparece os selecionados pelo usuário mas as tags disponíveis não aparecem.

Post

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{

protected $fillable = [
    'title', 
    'text',
    'slug',
];

public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'post_tag');
}

public function photos()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Photo', 'photoable');
}

}
```

Tag

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model
{

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 
];

public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
}

}
```

Controller

```
public function store(PostRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $this->post = new Post($data);
    $this->post->slug = str_slug($request->slug);
    $this->post->save();
    $this->post->tags()->sync($request->tag_id);

    if (!empty($this->photo = $request->file)) {
        foreach($this->photo as $photo) {
            $this->photo = new Photo();
            $this->photo->name = $photo->getClientOriginalName();
            $this->photo->photoable_id = $this->post->id;
            $this->photo->photoable_type = Post::class; 
            $path = $photo->storeAs('public', $this->photo->name);
            $this->photo->save();
        }
        Session::flash('alert-success', 'Post incluído com sucesso!');
        return redirect()->route('indexPost');
    }
    Session::flash('alert-success', 'Post incluído com sucesso!'); 
    return redirect()->route('indexPost');
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $tags = Tag::all();
    $this->post = Post::find($id);
    $photos = $this->post->photos;
    return view('post.edit')->with('post', $this->post)->with('tags', $tags)->with('photos', $photos);
}
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tag</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="select2 select2-multiple" multiple="multiple" multiple name="tag_id[]">
            @foreach($tags as $tag)
                @foreach($post->tags as $tags)
                    <option {{ $tag->id == $tags->id ? 'selected' : ''}} value="{{ $tag->id }}">{{ $tag->name }}</option> 
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
            </select>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algumas mudanças no seu código:

***Controller***

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $tags = Tag::all();
    $this->post = Post::with(['photos','tags'])->find($id);
    $photos = $this->post->photos;
    if (!is_null($this->post->tags)) {
        $tagsSelected = array_map(function($a){
            return $a['id'];
        }, $this->post->tags->toArray());
    }
    else 
    {
        $tagsSelected = array();
    }
    return view('post.edit')
             ->with('tagsSelected',$tagsSelected)
             ->with('post', $this->post)
             ->with('tags', $tags)
             ->with('photos', $photos);
}
```

---

***View***

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tag</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="select2 select2-multiple" 
                    multiple="multiple" multiple name="tag_id[]">
            @foreach($tags as $tag)                
               <option {{ in_array($tag->id,$tagsSelected) ? 'selected' : ''}} 
                                value="{{ $tag->id }}">
                 {{ $tag->name }}
               </option>     
            @endforeach
            </select>
      </div>
</div>
```